# How to highlight custom date in bootstrap date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im using angularjs for my project and bootstrap date-picker for select date.
In my project there is 2 input for select From date and To date. For the From date can select only today date, for the To date calculation i have add  1 year for from date using JavaScript and bind to To Date input. Data binding part is working fine. but when i click on To date its not show highlighted date in date-picker. Can i know how to highlight Today.

These are the option currently im used.

```
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true
```

[image]

Comment: have you imported bootstrap datepicker css?. if not  kindly import <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" /> and try.

Comment: Yes its already there. Today highlighted option is working fine. i want to highlight custom date which is already bind on to date input.

Comment: Can you show the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML You can use this.

```
<input name="dateInput" type="date" ng-model="TodayDate"/>
```

And In Controller you can get new Date(), So You can Assign the date to the ng-model.

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10){
    month = "0" + month;
};
if (day < 10) {
    day = '0' + day;
}
$scope.TodayDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```